# How to integrate Ganglia for Spark 2.1 Job metrics, Spark ignoring Ganglia metrics

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, emr, amazon-emr, ganglia

I am trying to integrate Spark 2.1 job's metrics to Ganglia.

My spark-default.conf looks like

```
*.sink.ganglia.class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink
*.sink.ganglia.name Name
*.sink.ganglia.host $MASTERIP
*.sink.ganglia.port $PORT

*.sink.ganglia.mode unicast
*.sink.ganglia.period 10
*.sink.ganglia.unit seconds
```

When i submit my job i can see the warn

```
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.host=host
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.name=Name
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.mode=unicast
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.period=10
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.port=8649
Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: *.sink.ganglia.unit=seconds
```

My environment details are

```
Hadoop : Amazon 2.7.3 - emr-5.7.0  
Spark  : Spark 2.1.1, 
Ganglia: 3.7.2
```

If you have any inputs or any other alternative of Ganglia please reply.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/monitoring.html#metrics)

> The metrics system is configured via a configuration file that Spark expects to be present at $SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties. A custom file location can be specified via the spark.metrics.conf configuration property.

so instead of having these confs in `spark-default.conf`, move them to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/metrics.properties`

Answer (score 1):

For EMR specifically, you'll need to put these settings in `/etc/spark/conf/metrics.properties` on the master node.

Spark on EMR does include the Ganglia library:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/spark/external/lib/spark-ganglia-lgpl_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28376 Mar 22 00:43 /usr/lib/spark/external/lib/spark-ganglia-lgpl_2.11-2.3.0.jar
```

In addition, your example is missing the equals sign (`=`) between the config names and values - unsure if that's an issue. Below is an example config that worked successfully for me.

```
*.sink.ganglia.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink
*.sink.ganglia.name=AMZN-EMR
*.sink.ganglia.host=$MASTERIP
*.sink.ganglia.port=8649

*.sink.ganglia.mode=unicast
*.sink.ganglia.period=10
*.sink.ganglia.unit=seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

From this page: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

```
Spark also supports a Ganglia sink which is not included in the default build due to licensing restrictions:

GangliaSink: Sends metrics to a Ganglia node or multicast group.
**To install the GangliaSink you’ll need to perform a custom build of Spark**. Note that by embedding this library you will include LGPL-licensed code in your Spark package. For sbt users, set the SPARK_GANGLIA_LGPL environment variable before building. For Maven users, enable the -Pspark-ganglia-lgpl profile. In addition to modifying the cluster’s Spark build user
```

Comment: I have used EMR Spark with Ganglia setup i hope which includes the package but its ignoring the metric configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone still needs this. But you have to make the full Ganglia configurations:

```
# Ganglia conf                                                                       
*.sink.ganglia.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink                       
*.sink.ganglia.name=AMZN-EMR                                                         
*.sink.ganglia.host=$MASTERIP                                                       
*.sink.ganglia.port=8649                                                             
                                                                                     
*.sink.ganglia.mode=unicast                                                          
*.sink.ganglia.period=10                                                             
*.sink.ganglia.unit=seconds                                                          
                                                                                     
# Enable JvmSource for instance master, worker, driver and executor                  
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource                    
worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource                    
driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource                    
executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

Even with the full configuration, I'm running into this issue from AWS EMR 5.33.0

```
21/05/26 14:18:20 ERROR org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem: Source class org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource                     cannot be instantiated
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource                    
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSources$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSources$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:181)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSources(MetricsSystem.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/05/26 14:18:20 ERROR org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem: Sink class org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink                        cannot be instantiated
21/05/26 14:18:20 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GangliaSink                       
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$registerSinks$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:196)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:130)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.registerSinks(MetricsSystem.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.start(MetricsSystem.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:528)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It's weird because AWS EMR should provide this dependency (`org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.4.7`) and I hope that the Spark distribution with AWS EMR is compiled with the Ganglia option. Forcing this jar on --packages or --jars spark options doesn't help either.

If someone manages to get Ganglia working with Spark on AWS EMR with driver/executors jvm monitoring. Please do tell me how.